# Python: Removing np nan values from String Array

Tags: python, pandas

How would can I remove np nan values from an array of strings?

I have a created a LIST where I am appending values that are not present in a DF based on another DF.

For Example:

```
NotPresent = [Alan, Susie, nan, nan, nan]
```

I want to be able to convert the list as so:

```
NotPresent = [Alan, Susie]
```

What is the simplest way to approach this in Python?

Thanks

Comment: Most definitely there are other questions in this site solving this problem, but are you dealing with lists or data frames? These are not the same thing and the answer differs in each case.

Comment: You mention DataFrame but your example specifies a list. If you're using a pandas DataFrame you can use the dropna() function.

Comment: Same suggestion.  If you are pulling from 2 DataFrames, just dropna() and never have those in your list in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nan is = np.nan then:

```
import numpy as np
import math
NotPresent = ["Alan", "Susie", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan] 
print(NotPresent)
n = len(NotPresent)
j = -1
for i in range(n):
  j += 1
  if not isinstance(NotPresent[j], str) and math.isnan(NotPresent[j]):
    del NotPresent[j]
    j = j-1
print(NotPresent)
```

The output will be:

`['Alan', 'Susie', nan, nan, nan]`

`['Alan', 'Susie']`

If "nan" is a string then:

```
NotPresent = ["Alan", "Susie", "nan", "nan", "nan"] 
print(NotPresent)
n = len(NotPresent)
j = -1
for i in range(n):
    j += 1
    if NotPresent[j] == "nan":
        del NotPresent[j]
        j -= 1
print(NotPresent)
```

The output will be:

`['Alan', 'Susie', "nan", "nan", "nan"]`

`['Alan', 'Susie']`

Answer (score 3):

If you really mean a `pandas DataFrame` then you can use `dropna()`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [['Alan'], ['Suzie'], [np.nan], [np.nan]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1'])
>>> df
    col1
0   Alan
1  Suzie
2    NaN
3    NaN
>>> df.dropna()
    col1
0   Alan
1  Suzie
```

Other folks have answered with their versions of handling `nan` in a list. Here's an alternative way of doing it using `nan` from `numpy`

```
>>> sample
['Alan', 'Suzie', nan, nan]
>>> from numpy import nan
>>> [x for x in sample if x is not nan]
['Alan', 'Suzie']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `filter`:

```
import numpy as np

NotPresent = ["Alan", "Susie", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan] 

NotPresent = list(filter(lambda i: not i is np.nan, NotPresent))

print(NotPresent)
```

Output:

```
['Alan', 'Susie']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
[x for x in NotPresent if str(x) != 'nan']
Out[1543]: ['Alan', 'Susie']
```